# Dropbox java login

Tags: java, dropbox-api

Im trying to integrate the DropBox into my java app but I didn't understood how can I create a general login (email and password each time someone click 'log in'). I used the token to access data from my account, but now I want get from anyone who logs in.

Comment: please post your current code

Comment: Your question is far too vague. Log into who's account, yours or theirs? By token do you mean the Authentication Code from DropBox (which is required regardless of what account you're accessing) or the App Secret and App Key? I think the tutorial [here](http://javapapers.com/java/dropbox-java-api-tutorial/) and the link [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/java) should get you on your way. Or are you simply asking how to create a window which merely asks the User for a Email Address and a Password?

Comment: @devilshnd I want to have permission to see their dropbox files to manipulate in my app, I have the app secret and app key, but the tutorial I saw in dropbox api, they used just the token. I'm really lost in how I can do this log in to get permission of theirs...

Comment: first of all try the official [dropbox api sdk](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java). Secondly, are you trying to sign in to Dropbox using an email account? thats what i understand when you say email and password.

Answer (score 0):

Your app can obtain an access token by redirecting the user to the appropriate URL (preferably within a web browser, otherwise something like a webview), where they will sign in with their dropbox credentials (username, password).
After this, they will be redirected back to your app, and you can now get the access token (token secret) as part of the response.
You should then store this somewhere, and propbably keep using it, till the user asks you to log out of their Dropbox account, in which case you should then get rid of that access token (token secret).

You can refer to this page for the specifics on how to do it:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/web-file-browser/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/web_file_browser/DropboxAuth.java

Another useful link:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide

NOTE: The 'access token' that you used so far was probably just an access token provided by Dropbox to your app for testing purposes only.
To actually access the user's Dropbox, you would need to obtain an access token for each user, using the method described above.